# Conditional background colour for grid cells in OroCRM

Tags: orocrm

Is it possible to conditionally change the colour of a cell in a grid in OroCRM if the value of the cell matches one of a number of options?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom class to the column value wrapper or any other conditional logic to the column HTML by providing a custom twig template for it.

See the `template` option in a `columns` section:
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/configuration/yaml/datagrids/#reference-datagrid-columns